# PHP/ SQL restricting viewing rights

Tags: php, sql

I want to ensure "StaffID" is stored when the "View Contacts" page is loaded from a link, rather than straight from the Login Form

LOGIN FORM:

```
<?php session_start(); // Start PHP session

$StaffID = isset($_SESSION["StaffID"]) ? $_SESSION["StaffID"] : "";?>

<form name="staffaccess" method="post" action="staff-login.php">
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Staff Login </strong></td>
</tr>

<input type="hidden" name="StaffID" id="StaffID" value="<?php echo $StaffID; ?>" />

<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input name="StaffUsername" size= "30" type="text" id="StaffUsername" value="<?php echo $StaffUsername; ?>"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input name="StaffPassword" size= "30" type="text" id="StaffPassword" value="<?php echo $StaffPassword; ?>"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

LOGIN CHECK:

```
<?php session_start(); // Start PHP session?>
<body>

<?php


$_SESSION["StaffUsername"] = isset($_POST["StaffUsername"]) ? $_POST["StaffUsername"] : "";
$_SESSION["StaffPassword"] = isset($_POST["StaffPassword"]) ? $_POST["StaffPassword"] : "";
$_SESSION["StaffID"] = isset($_GET["StaffID"]) ? $_GET["StaffID"] : "";

<?php

//connect to database//
$dbc = mysql_connect("", "", "");
if (!$dbc)
die ('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());

//select database//
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("tafe", $dbc );
if (!$db_selected)
die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 


 // username and password sent from form 
 $StaffUsername=$_POST['StaffUsername']; 
 $StaffPassword=$_POST['StaffPassword']; 



// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
 $StaffUsername = stripslashes($StaffUsername);
 $StaffPassword = stripslashes($StaffPassword);
 $StaffUsername = mysql_real_escape_string($StaffUsername);
 $StaffPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($StaffPassword);

$qry=("SELECT * FROM staffaccess WHERE Username= '" . $StaffUsername . "' AND Password= '" .$StaffPassword ."'");


$rst = mysql_query($qry, $dbc);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rst);


if ($row["Username"]==$StaffUsername && $row["Password"]==$StaffPassword)
{
    $_SESSION["StaffID"] = $row["StaffID"];
echo "Your login was successful";
echo "</br></br>";
echo "<a href=list-contacts.php>Continue</a>";
}

else {

echo "Sorry your details are not valid";
echo "</br></br>";
echo "<a href=staff-login.htm>Return</a>";
}


 ?>
```

VIEW CONTACTS (i only want this to allow to view contacts that particular user has added)

```
<?php 


//connect to database

$dbc = mysql_connect("", "", "");
if (!$dbc)
die ('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());

//select database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("tafe", $dbc );
if (!$db_selected)
die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

$StaffID = (int)$_GET['StaffId'];

// build sql insert statement
**$qry = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE StaffID= $StaffID ORDER by name ASC";**

//run insert satement against database
$rst = mysql_query($qry, $dbc);

// print whether successful or not
if ($rst)
{
if (mysql_num_rows($rst)>0) // check that there are records
{


    echo "<table border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\">";

    /***print out field names***/

    echo "<tr>"; // start row
    for ($i=0; $i<mysql_num_fields($rst); $i++) // for each field print out field name
    {
        echo "<th>" . mysql_field_name($rst, $i) . "</th>";

    }
        echo "<th>&nbsp;</th>";
        echo "<th>&nbsp;</th>";
    echo "</tr>";



    /***print out field values***/

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rst)) // fetch each of the rows
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['ContactID']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Address']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Phone']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Mobile']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='edit-contact.php?id=".$row['ContactID']."'>Edit</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='delete-contact.php?id=".$row['ContactID']."'>Delete</a></td><tr>";
        echo "</tr>";


    }


    echo "</table>";


}
else
{
    echo "<b><font color='black'>No records returned.</font></b>";
}
}
else
{
echo "<b><font color='red'>Error: ".mysql_error($dbc) . "</font></b>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didnt pass the staff id on contact page so you pass the staff id like this

change following change in logincheck page

```
if ($row["Username"]==$StaffUsername && $row["Password"]==$StaffPassword)
{
echo "Your login was successful";
echo "</br></br>";
echo "<a href=list-contacts.php?StaffId=".$row["StaffId"].">Continue</a>";
}
```

you can also use session for logged user

Comment: Thanks, I have added that in however it is still not working. It may be a problem with the way the tables are set up.
Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: check you column name in stafftabel

Comment: I seemed to have fixed that problem however now have a new problem; the query is only bringing up contacts with StaffID (0). and all users can access those contacts. Any thoughts as to what has gone wrong here?

Comment: check $_GET['StaffId'] value before fetch the record form database in contact page like this

if(!isset($_GET['StaffId']) || empty($_GET['StaffId']))
  die('show error');

$StaffID = (int)$_GET['StaffId'];

Comment: Oh gosh, I just worked out I had StaffID in some places and StaffId in others! always the smallest thing! thank you for your help

Comment: How would I go about ensuring the Staff ID is remembered on the next page load? e.g. it is working fine when the "view contacts" page is loaded directly after the login form/ login check file however from then if you click on any other link back to the "view contacts" page, it does not remember the StaffID and says there are no contacts. I have tried adding SESSIONS however can not get it to work.

Comment: do you use session_start(); on top of page?

Comment: yep on the top of each page followed by $StaffID = isset($_SESSION["StaffID"]) ? $_SESSION["StaffID"] : ""

Comment: how you set the session $_SESSION["StaffID"]?

show you actual code

Comment: you not assign the StaffID into session variable after login check 
I have corrected the code which mention above so check updated code

Comment: sorry, it isn't returning any records at all now but I could have changed something else which is causing it. I will take a closer look at it, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you mysql version, you may need to quote your where properties, I'm not sure if this is causing your problem, but it may be related.  Also, are you sure that your value for the StaffID field is being correctly inserted into the database?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code and you are using

```
echo "<a href=list-contacts.php>Continue</a>";
```

to send user to see the contacts and in this page you are doing

```
$StaffID = (int)$_GET['StaffId'];
```

So you need to pass that value in the query string as

```
echo "<a href=list-contacts.php?StaffId=".$row["column_name_in_table"].">Continue</a>";
```